# Match consecutive 2 digit or 3 digit

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I am running this function to generate a wordlist of 256 words. then I use the second declaration to filter out bad matches and I am left with just 54 words. I am looking for a way to match this using regex or other way so that it looks clean and not so sloppy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
GenerateStrings(new char[] { 'D', 'U' }, 8);

        public IEnumerable<String> GenerateStrings(IEnumerable<char> characters, int length) {
        if (length > 0) {
            foreach (char c in characters) {
                foreach (String suffix in GenerateStrings(characters, length - 1)) {
                    yield return c + suffix;
                }
            }
        } else {
            yield return string.Empty;
        }
    }


            
            if (!eachWord.Contains("UUUUU") && !eachWord.Contains("DDDDD") && !eachWord.Contains("UUUUD") && !eachWord.Contains("DDDDU") && !eachWord.Contains("UUUDDDD") && !eachWord.Contains("DDDUUUU")) {
                if (!eachWord.StartsWith("UUUU") && !eachWord.StartsWith("DDDD")) {
                    if (eachWord.StartsWith("UUDD") || eachWord.StartsWith("DDUU") || eachWord.StartsWith("DDUUU") ||
                            eachWord.StartsWith("UUDDD") || eachWord.StartsWith("DDDUU") || eachWord.StartsWith("UUUDD") ||
                            eachWord.StartsWith("DUUDD") || eachWord.StartsWith("DDDUU") || eachWord.StartsWith("DDDUUU") ||
                            eachWord.StartsWith("DUUDDD") || eachWord.StartsWith("DDDDUU") || eachWord.StartsWith("DUUUDD") ||
                            eachWord.StartsWith("UUUDD") || eachWord.StartsWith("UDDUU") || eachWord.StartsWith("UDDUUU") ||
                            eachWord.StartsWith("UUUDDD") || eachWord.StartsWith("UDDDUU") || eachWord.StartsWith("UUUUDD")) {

                            //good word
                        
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the logic behind the filter? Because there are similar patterns which are included as well as excluded. Some words and sample output or the logic behind filter will help us.

Comment: every time I try to explain it no one ever understands it so I just posted the filter.. so basically any consecutive 2 or 3 digits like UUDD or like UUDDD or like DDDUUU but not UUDUU

Comment: Do you mean like this? `U{2,3}D{2,3}(?!D)|D{2,3}U{2,3}(?!U)` https://regex101.com/r/rfiq69/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I am getting 108 results instead of 54

Comment: Can you add all the names to a https://regex101.com link and share it here and point out which ones should match?

Comment: @Thefourthbird here's the link https://regex101.com/r/FBo0Km/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match all the good value, you might use an alternation in combination with a negative lookahead `(?!` excluding some characters to the right.

```
^(?:D?UUU?DD(?!DD)|U?DDD?UUU?(?!U))[UD]+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `D?UUU?DD(?!DD)` Match optional `D`, then UU and optional `U`, then DD and assert not `DD` after it directly to the right
  - `|` Or
  - `U?DDD?UUU?(?!U)` Match optional `U`, then `DD` and optional `D`, then `UU` and optional `U` asserting not `U` directly to the right.
- `)` Close non capture group
- `[UD]+` Match 1+ times either `U` or `D`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HSMxdx/1)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code. I suppose this is the pattern you are looking for.

```
        string[] arrSTr ={"UUDUU", "UUDDD", "UUUDD", "DDDUUU", "UUUDDD","DDUDD"};
        foreach(string s in arrSTr)
        {
            foreach (Match x in Regex.Matches(s, "[U]{2,}[D]{2,}|[D]{2,}[U]{2,}"))
            {
                if (!x.Success) { continue; }
                Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
            }
        }
```

I tried and tested the regex in https://regex101.com/.

Thanks @The fourth bird for the idea on |.

Comment: I am getting 128 results instead of 54

Comment: @XK8ER the logic seems odd to me. UDUUUDDD is Bad but UDDUUUDU is good. UUUDDD matches the description of 3 consecutive. So it must be good. I'm confused here.

Comment: i know its confusing that why I have a hard time explaining but I posted the good ones and bad ones here https://regex101.com/r/FBo0Km/1